# GCP BIGQUERY YTD CUMILATIVE SUM BASED on MONTH

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My current SQL returns the below results based on some calculations for Workdays Month and YTD and FTE Month and YTD.

| Version | CALENDAR_MONTH | CALENDAR_DATE | AMOUNT | Workdays_Month | FTE_MONTH | Workdays_YTD | FTE_YTD | Correct FTE_YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTA | 201907 | 31/07/2019 | 31062.9 | 23 | 183.75 | 23 | 183.75 | 183.75 |
| ACTA | 201908 | 31/08/2019 | 30509.1 | 22 | 188.68 | 45 | 92.24 | 275.99 |
| ACTA | 201909 | 30/09/2019 | 28712.49 | 21 | 186.02 | 66 | 59.19 | 335.18 |
| ACTA | 201910 | 31/10/2019 | 47656.37 | 23 | 281.91 | 89 | 72.85 | 408.03 |
| ACTA | 201911 | 30/11/2019 | 32033.98 | 21 | 207.54 | 110 | 39.62 | 447.65 |
| ACTA | 201912 | 31/12/2019 | 32788.36 | 22 | 202.77 | 132 | 33.80 | 481.45 |
| ACTA | 202001 | 31/01/2020 | 31983.77 | 23 | 189.20 | 155 | 28.07 | 509.52 |
| ACTA | 202002 | 29/02/2020 | 37647.87 | 20 | 256.11 | 175 | 29.27 | 538.79 |
| ACTA | 202003 | 31/03/2020 | 35203.83 | 22 | 217.71 | 197 | 24.31 | 563.11 |
| ACTA | 202004 | 30/04/2020 | 35476.7 | 22 | 219.40 | 219 | 22.04 | 585.15 |
| ACTA | 202005 | 31/05/2020 | -1083.81 | 21 | -7.02 | 240 | -0.61 | 584.53 |
| ACTA | 202006 | 30/06/2020 | 20766.45 | 22 | 128.43 | 262 | 10.78 | 595.32 |

I would like to update my FTE_YTD Calculation to be a cumulative sum of previous month/s based on   CALENDAR_MONTH  CALENDAR_DATE

Note: Financial Year is from 1/07 to 30/6

```
My current Calculations


(select count(*) from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc(CALENDAR_DATE, month), last_day(CALENDAR_DATE, month ))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)) as Workdays_Month,

(SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT,(SAFE_MULTIPLY((select count(*) from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc(CALENDAR_DATE, month), last_day(CALENDAR_DATE, month ))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)),7.35))))  as FTE_MONTH,


(select count(*) 
from unnest([struct(extract(year from CALENDAR_DATE) as year, extract(month from CALENDAR_DATE) as month)]),
unnest(generate_date_array(if(month < 7, date(year - 1, 7, 1), date(year, 7, 1)), last_day(date(year, month, 1)))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)) as Workdays_YTD,


(SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT,(SAFE_MULTIPLY((select count(*) 
from unnest([struct(extract(year from CALENDAR_DATE) as year, extract(month from CALENDAR_DATE) as month)]),
unnest(generate_date_array(if(month < 7, date(year - 1, 7, 1), date(year, 7, 1)), last_day(date(year, month, 1)))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)),7.35))))  as FTE_YTD,
```

I would like to update my FTE_YTD Calculation to be a cumulative sum of previous month/s based on   CALENDAR_MONTH  CALENDAR_DATE

Comment: please present your input data!

Comment: Do you mean the calculation formula?  FTE_MONTH = sum(Amount)/max(workDays_Month*7.35) and FTE_YTD = Sum(YTD_Amount)/max(workDays_YTD*7.35) ......So I am trying to figure out how to calculate YTD Amount

Comment: i meant initial data that you produced shown result from. but nevermind - i don't think i need it actually :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last select statement should be as below

```
round(sum(
(SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT,(SAFE_MULTIPLY((select count(*) 
from unnest([struct(extract(year from CALENDAR_DATE) as year, extract(month from CALENDAR_DATE) as month)]),
unnest(generate_date_array(if(month < 7, date(year - 1, 7, 1), date(year, 7, 1)), last_day(date(year, month, 1)))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)),7.35))))
) over(partition by extract(year from date_add(CALENDAR_DATE, interval 6 month)) order by CALENDAR_DATE), 2) as FTE_YTD,
```

so the output will be

[image]

Another option (to potentially avoid "resource exceeded ...") is to wrap your current query with below

```
select * except(FTE_YTD), 
  round(sum(FTE_YTD) over(partition by extract(year from date_add(CALENDAR_DATE, interval 6 month)) order by CALENDAR_DATE), 2) as FTE_YTD
from (
  ....
)
```

with same output

Comment: Error running query
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 123% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 99% other/unattributed: 1%

Comment: see update in my answer to potentially address resource exceeded error

Comment: no luck with both options, still gives me the resource exceeded error

Comment: have your original query actually produced result or also errored? try to move `extract(year from date_add(CALENDAR_DATE, interval 6 month))` into your original query so then in outside query you will avoid redundant calculation of year

Comment: Tried it but no luck... I think I am struggling with calculating YTD_AMOUNT

Comment: (SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT,(SAFE_MULTIPLY((select count(*) 
from unnest([struct(extract(year from CALENDAR_DATE) as year, extract(month from CALENDAR_DATE) as month)]),
unnest(generate_date_array(if(month < 7, date(year - 1, 7, 1), date(year, 7, 1)), last_day(date(year, month, 1)))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)),7.35))))  as FTE_YTD, -->Question --> How do I change AMOUNT to YTD AMOUNT?